# css conditions for browser

Tags: html, css

can you have a setting for say margin-right for different browsers in the css page like i want margin-right for google chrome or mozila browsers and another margin right for ie e.g

if ie
margin-right: -1px;
if mozilla
margin-right: -2px;

like switches in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not actual *switches* (in the strictest sense) for CSS. For IE, in HTML, you can use [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment), like the following:

```html
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Conditional comments allow you to override default CSS with IE-only (or specific version(s) of IE-only) CSS to fix some quirks with CSS.

For actual coding, you could sniff out the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) of a browser using JavaScript or PHP, and dynamically generating CSS based on the user agent.